# Using same ISO for multiple VM's

Tags: vmware-workstation

the question is rather simple but I cannot hunt down the answer . I have an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on a vmware . For some testing purpose I need to launch another Ubuntu 14.04 LTS iso . I would like to know if I can use the same existing ISO i have for my older vmware install or will it screw up my old install ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the existing ISO should be fine.  Think of it like installing Ubuntu on 2 different computers with the same installation CD.